# Why does jQuery delete what's in my DIV's and how do I stop it from doing so?

Tags: jquery, dom, text, append, attr

Here's some code I've got in my sandbox.php file:

```
  <div class="jq">
    <img class="active" id="also" alt="Fifty-Fifty?" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  </div>
  <div id="title">
    This is the alt element of the 350x150 image, found by class.  It should return 'Fifty-Fifty?':
    <script>
      $("#title").text($('.jq .active').attr('alt'));
    </script>
  </div>
```

So, I'm just trying to figure out why "This is the alt element..." gets scrubbed, and I want to know how to keep that from happening.  I actually don't feel that I need a 'title' div.  I feel like I could just append the text into the 'jq' section.

Could someone explain why people over structure documents, also?  I'm looking at the code for StackOverflow, and they put all of the links in their `hlinks-custom`-id'd div in that div.  The anchors make it very clear structural separator, and it doesn't seem anything more is needed.  Go to YouTube.com, though, and you'll see that every single link on the page has its own div.  Does that not seem strange?

Comment: It deletes it because you tell it to do so. `text`: *"Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text."*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `.append()`, like so:

```
$("#title").append($('.jq .active').attr('alt'));
```

[Here is a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/x7XxS/)

Comment: This one works.  I don't know why the other code that many users submitted didn't work.  When I tested it, I could see the raw code rather than the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're replacing, not appending. Try:

```
var $t = $("#title");
$t.text($t.text() + $('.jq .active').attr('alt'));
```

Comment: Why did you make a variable?  I like it because it's new and interesting, but I don't understand why it was necessary.  If you don't mind my asking...

Comment: Just to cache the selection by creating a re-useable reference, rather than calling the same selection every time. I think it is more readable like that.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix you problem -

```
    <script>
      $("#title").text($("#title").text() + $('.jq .active').attr('alt'));
    </script>
```

The `text` function will replace all text content within the selected element. So you need to append the original text to the text you want to add, then pass all of that to the `text` function.

Comment: For some reason, it's returning "$('.jq .active').attr('alt'));" instead of "Fifty-fifty".

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 - yes, that's odd. I think it's something to do with the script block being situated inside the div that's changing. It works if the script is moved outside the div or if the code is run in a `document.ready` block

Comment: I have no idea what that means, really.  I'm using this stuff to learn the DOM.  I'll try to figure it out.  Meanwhile, it just doesn't work as is. :/

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the text of the title div so you are in affect clearing it and setting it again. You are looking for the [jquery append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function.

```
<script>
    $("#title").append($('.jq .active').attr('alt'));
</script>
```

Comment: See comment on ipr101's post.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Are you copying the code directly? The only thing I can think of is if you put quotes around the jquery. That would cause it to think it is a string. Can you make a jsFiddle with an exmaple of what you are seeing?

Comment: Yah.  Sorry misaimed comment.  The code they gave me doesn:t work.  The append code works, though. +  Thanks, man. ~~

Answer (score 1):

The `.text(value)` method sets the content of the div to the `value`. Therefore, what was in the div before is removed to make room for the new content.

You may want to use the `.append(value)` method instead. It appends the value to the end of the div's content.